# iOS / MonoTouch: Become first responder

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a single view in my application which does not receive any events from iOS. I tried to call "BecomeFirstResponder" but this does not work and the method returns false.

Here is the code which creates the view:

```
_Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
View = new ApplicationView(this);
_Window.RootViewController = new UIViewController();
_Window.Add(View);
_Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

Thats the code which handles the input( ApplicationView; Base class is iPhoneOSGameView which has UIView as base class ):

```
public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    foreach (UITouch item in touches.ToArray<UITouch>())
    {
        _Stage.MapTouchesBegan(new TouchEvent((Int32)item.Handle, item.LocationInView(this)));
    }
}
```

The method is never called.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks wrong. The UIViewController assigned to root does nothing. Also I think you meant to use window.AddSubview(). Does the code above even build?
Does your view fill the entire screen? It only will receive touches inside its frame.

You might want to take a look at the basics of the model view controller concept (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) and also at some samples that get you started with iOS development in Monotouch (https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The view is visible over the entire screen and the "add" is used in the sample from "MonoGame" ( http://monogame.codeplex.com/ ) which works. I found out that the ViewController receives all input ( I can't focus the view ) and made a little workaround as long the problem itself is not solved.

Comment: Just don't set the root view controller. Setting an empty controller is pointless IMHO.

Comment: Hmm, when not setting the root view controller iOS gives me a message that i should do it.

Comment: Yeah, you _should_ but you don't have to. You should in fact have a view controller that manages your game view and use that as the root controller. If you add an arbitrary controller as root, it will have a view that covers the whole screen automagically.

Comment: You've been right, just forget to accept your answer. Thank you anyway